# Как изменить цвет левой колонки DataGridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Как можно изменить цвет левой колонки DataGridView?

[image: То что есть]

Comment: 1. Сайт на русском. 2. К WPF вопрос никакого отношения не имеет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильней называть это заголовком (хедером) строк.

Чтобы можно было применять к ним стили вручную, нужно отключить визуальный стиль текущей темы пользователя.

```
dataGridView.EnableHeadersVisualStyles = false;

dataGridView.RowHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Pink;
```

Comment: Спасибо, не знал что это заголовок строки, вот и мучался, помогло, спасибо))